# Summation Evaluation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, numpy

Given
`z = np.linspace(1,10,100)`

Calculate Summation over all values of z in `z^k * exp((-z^2)/ 2)`

```
import numpy as np
import math

def calc_Summation1(z, k):
    ans = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(z)):`
        ans += math.pow(z[i], k) * math.exp(math.pow(-z[i], 2) / 2)
    return ans

def calc_Summation2(z,k):
     part1 = z**k
     part2 = math.exp(-z**2 / 2)
     return np.dot(part1, part2.transpose())
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with both `calc_Summation1` and `calc_Summation2`?

Comment: The - is in the wrong place in the exponential. You have `math.exp(math.pow(-z[i], 2) / 2)` you want `math.exp(-math.pow(z[i], 2) / 2)`

Comment: For the second use `part2 = map(math.exp,-z**2 / 2)` and `return np.dot(part1, part2)` no need to transpose 1D arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to vectorize calculations with numpy, you need to use numpy's ufuncs. Also, the usual way of doing you calculation would be:

```
import numpy as np

calc = np.sum(z**k * np.exp(-z*z / 2))
```

although you can keep your approach using `np.dot` if you call `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`:

```
calc = np.dot(z**k, np.exp(-z*z / 2))
```

It does run faster with dot:

```
In [1]: z = np.random.rand(1000)

In [2]: %timeit np.sum(z**5 * np.exp(-z*z / 2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 142 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.dot(z**5, np.exp(-z*z / 2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop

In [4]: np.allclose(np.sum(z**5 * np.exp(-z*z / 2)),
...                 np.dot(z**5, np.exp(-z*z / 2)))
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
sum(z_i**k * math.exp(-z_i**2 / 2) for z_i in z)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k=1
def myfun(z_i):
    return z_i**k * math.exp(-z_i**2 / 2)
sum(map(myfun,z))
```

We define a function for the thing we want to sum, use the `map` function to apply it to each value in the list and then sum all these values. Having to use an external variable `k` is slightly niggling.

A refinement would be to define a two argument function

```
def myfun2(z_i,k):
    return z_i**k * math.exp(-z_i**2 / 2)
```

and use a lambda expression to evaluate it

```
sum(map(lambda x:myfun2(x,1), z))
```

Comment: Please explain behavior of your change